# group actions on fibre bundles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, group-actions, fibre-bundles, principal-bundles

Suppose that we have a group $G$ acting on the spaces $E$ and  $B$. Suppose moreover that we have fibre bundles $\xi$ and $\eta$ in the following commutative diagram[image]

If $\xi$ is a trivial bundle, i.e. the Cartesian product, whether could we conclude that $\eta$ is trivial as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. let $F$ have a $G$-action, take $B=EG$ and $E=EG \times F$ with the diagonal action. Then $\eta$ is the Borel construction $EG \times_G F \to BG$ so need not be trivial.